# Merge sort in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

In competitive coding i got a question to code merge sort
I know how to code merge sort with three arguments ie

```
merge_sort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
     \\rest of code
}
```

But the question was

```
merge_sort(int arr[],int size)
{
     \\rest of code
}
```

How to perform merge sort for 2 arguments?

Comment: Can you write a helper function? You can also write a recursive lambda function.

Comment: How competitive is this coding? A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) would be slightly faster. There is no recursion, so no need to have a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
merge_sort(int arr[],int size)
{
     merge_sort(arr, 0,size-1) // merge_sort(int arr[],int left,int right)
}
```

Now you call the 3 argument function from the 2 argument one.

Comment: @Priyank of course. merge_sort(arr, 0,size-1) is your recursive merge_sort function which takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Great!! Will try for sure

Comment: @Priyank I am happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can call this function

```
merge_sort(int arr[],int size)
{
     \\rest of code
}
```

from this function

```
merge_sort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
     \\rest of code
}
```

like

```
merge_sort( arr + left, right - left + 1 );
```

In this case relative to the second function the parameter `left` will be equal to `0` while the parameter right will be equal to `right - left + 1` due to moving the pointer to the required part of the array.

So the first function can substitute the second function by using appropriate arguments and the pointer arithmetic.

Or the second function can be called from the first function like

```
merge_sort( arr, 0, size - 1 );
```

Comment: Int main calls the function with 2 arguments ie with array and size. How to perform merge sort with 2 arguments only or How to go to the function with 3 arguments ie with array left and right?

Comment: @Priyank In fact in the first call you have left is equal to 0 and the right is equal to the size - 1.

Comment: @Priyank As I wrote using the pointer arithmetic the first function can call itself by setting the pointer to the desired position. I showed how arguments from one function can be converted to arguments to another function.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

`int arr[]` looks like an array, but it isn't. Remember that arrays decay to pointers to the first element when passed to functions. The first method uses:

```
-------------------------------------
|                 |             |
arr(pointer)      left(index)   right(index)
```

While the second can do the same with:

```
-------------------------------------
                  |<-- size  -->|
                  arr
```

Comment: @Priyank by calling the function recursively. `arr + left` is a pointer to the element at index `left`

Comment: @Priyank there is a one to one relation between parameters to one version and parameters to the other (as I tried to illustrate). If you know how to do recursion with one you can do the same with the other

Comment: @Priyank well, not quite. You cannot call the first from the second because it has no pointer to the first element, but the other way around should not be a problem

Comment: Thanks  I'll try